# Postgres pg_notify does not notify when a table gets updated from a stored procedure that is called via the Timescaledb Action's job scheduler

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, timescaledb

I have two tables in my **Postgres** DB. Table A is where all the data is stored. A stored procedure (X) does some aggregation of the data in Table A and has insert/update statement for Table B. Using the [**Timescaledb Actions's**](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/actions) job scheduler, every 1 hour X is called and table B gets updated or a new data is inserted in it. I have another trigger (T) that is triggered every time Table B gets updated or when a new record is inserted in it, the trigger simply `PERFORM pg_notify('channel',payload)`. Python backend receives the notification by executing `Listen` command from the `psycopg2`.

When I try to `INSERT/UPDATE` with random data in Table B, Python receives the Notification. But Python does not receives any notification when Stored Procedure update/inserts in Table B. The trigger (T) is not triggered when Table B gets updated or inserted from the Stored Procedure X.

I have read the [Notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) documentation. But I am sure I might have missed something important. If anyone could help me with this, I will be grateful.

```
--TRIGGER FUNCTION TO NOTIFY 
CREATE FUNCTION newDataTableB() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
    payload TEXT;
BEGIN   
    rec := new;
    payload := json_build_object(TG_OP, rec.id);
    -- Notify the channel
    PERFORM pg_notify('db_notifications', payload);
    RETURN rec;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- TRIGGER ON TABLE B
CREATE TRIGGER newDataTableB_tr AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON tableB FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE newDataTableB();


--Stored Procedure 
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertIntoTableB(job_id int, config jsonb) LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
DECLARE
    rec_findSpeed record;
    cur_findSpeed refcursor;
BEGIN
    --materialized view to find average of Speed stored in table A that is group by trip_id 
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW findSpeed;

    open cur_findSpeed for SELECT * from findSpeed;
    loop
        fetch cur_findSpeed into rec_findSpeed;
        exit when not found;
        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE trip_id = rec_findSpeed.trip_id) THEN
            update tableB set averageSpeed=rec_findSpeed.averageSpeed, min_time = rec_findSpeed.min_time where trip_id = rec_findSpeed.trip_id;
        ELSE
            INSERT into tableB(averageSpeed, min_time, trip_id)
            values(rec_findSpeed.averageSpeed, rec_findSpeed.min_time, rec_findSpeed.trip_id)
        END IF;
    end loop;
    close cur_findSpeed;
END;
$$;
SELECT add_job('insertIntoTableB','1h');


-- MATERIALIZED VIEW
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW findSpeed AS
    SELECT AVG(speed) as averageSpeed, trip_id, min(time) as min_time
    FROM tableA
    GROUP BY trip_id
    WITH DATA;
```

Python code as requested. The Python backend requires to execute some other queries after it receives the notification. I followed the [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html). I didn't understand everything as I am new to psycopg2. Please, tell me how should I proceed with this.

```
def wait(conn):
    while True:
        state = conn.poll()
        if state == psycopg2.extensions.POLL_OK:
            break
        elif state == psycopg2.extensions.POLL_WRITE:
            select.select([], [conn.fileno()], [])
        elif state == psycopg2.extensions.POLL_READ:
            select.select([conn.fileno()], [], [])
        else:
            raise psycopg2.OperationalError("poll() returned %s" % state)

@app.route('/startListening', methods=['POST'])     
def listen():    
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn, async_=True)
    wait(conn)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("LISTEN db_notifications")
    wait(conn)
    print("Listening on db_notifications")
    while True: 
        conn.poll()
        while conn.notifies:
            notify = conn.notifies.pop()
            print(notify)
            handle_event(notify, conn)

def handle_event(noti,connec):
    data_from_notifications = noti.payload
    print(data_from_notifications)
    #some data processing
    #next cursor and query 
    acur = connec.cursor()
    acur.execute('')
    wait(connec)
```

The problem is the Timescaldb's action job scheduler. I moved to pgAgent job scheduler, and everything was working exactly how it's supposed to be.

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure please?

Comment: Are the changes being committed in the procedure?

Comment: The trigger really should fire. You could add a raise statements (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) directly after the insert and update statements. This way we can see if the trigger really writes into `tableB`. The findSpeed view makes me suspicious.

Comment: @Jeremy the tableB gets updated or a new row is inserted in it from the procedure.

Comment: @jhinghaus The view works fine, it has data in it. I have added the view as well.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is somewhere else. Can you listen to the notifications in psql (interactive terminal)? I would like to get psycopg2 out of the scenario.

Comment: Your mat view doesn't have the correct column for your procedure to work.  Also, please show the CREATE TABLE for the tables.

Comment: @jjanes sorry, that was my fault. I updated it. thanks

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL is this (including the minor bug-fix release number)?

Comment: It might be necessary on the python side to take some action to actually receive the notification. (Python calling libpq's PQnotifies() function)

Comment: @jjanes `postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.2`

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe the problem is on the python side.

Comment: If it works for @jjanes, the problem has to be in the python code. Do you commit your `listen ...` query, before you `poll()` on the cursor? 
Please share the python code with us as well.

Comment: @jhinghaus I have added the python code.

Comment: @jjanes python code added

Comment: I'm not familiar with the async_=True option.  But experimentally, once I replace the empty query (which throws an error) with `select 1`, the python also works for me.  When I call the proc (from another session) my python gets one notification for each row

Comment: @jjanes could you please share your python code, please?

Comment: @jjanes I see that you have answered questions about Timescaledb. I have used Timescaledb's action to schedule the job to call the procedure. Is the problem because of that? (I have updated my question and added timescaledb `add_job`)

Comment: In order to isolate whether it's a Timescale problem or not can you run the procedure normally from another session, ie just SELECT <foo>(); and see if you get the notifications? If you do, then please file a bug in our github as that would likely be a bug in the background scheduling bit...

Comment: @davidk yes, I have called the procedure by `call insertIntoTableB()`. And the notifications works. I will file a bug in github. Thanks. I also shifted to pgAgent job scheduling and everything was working exactly how I wanted it to. The only reason I was using Timescale because it provides way more features than the pgAgent. I hope the bug gets solved soon.

Comment: Okay. Please do file a bug report, we'd like those from users in our github as it makes it much easier to track.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the python code.
Could you try this, without the server context of your example?

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn, async_=True)    
conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)    
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("LISTEN db_notifications")
r, w, e = select.select([conn.fileno()], [], [], timeout)
conn.poll()
for n in conn.notifies:
    print(n.channel)
    print(n)
```

Comment: In the documentation, it says that `it is not possible to use methods like commit() and rollback()` for asynchronous connection

Comment: @m-gupta You can try it with `async_=False` and the `commit()`or use the connection with autocommit. Did you try removing the first wait()?

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution with `async_= false`. It didn't work. :(

Comment: Can you try `LISTEN db_notifications` on the psql command line please?

Comment: When I do Notify "db_notifications" from psql, i get this. `Asynchronous notification "db_notifications" with payload "{"INSERT" : 10}" received from server process with PID 36692. Asynchronous notification "db_notifications" received from server process with PID 33076.`

Comment: @m-gupta What did you do to get this output? Is one notification from a manual insert and one from the trigger or is it both from the trigger?
Whatever the case one of the notifies seems to have no payload.

Comment: So, first I did `Listen db_notifications`, then I did  `Notify db_notifications`. I got the above result.  The first output is of when the trigger was fired when tableB got updated from the procedure and then the next one was when `Notify db_notifications` was fired from psql. At one time, when I fired `Notify db_notifications` in psql I got output with all the Notifications that was queued in the stack, and the last output was of Notify executed in psql with no payload. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230494/discussion-between-jhinghaus-and-m-gupta).

Comment: I think, the problem is postgres. I tried to `Listen` via [socketio_pg](https://pypi.org/project/socketio-pg/). The server only received Notifications when I manually inserted or manually `notify`.